# Magento 2 Web API pre/post dispatch events (REST/SOAP)

Tags: magento2, module, api, soap, rest-api

Is there any pre/post dispatch events for the Magento 2 web API (REST/SOAP) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no events in Magento 2 web APIs, but it is possible to extend any public method in the system using befor/after/around [plugins](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html). Also see why it is [better to use plugins](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93964/697) instead of observers.

Comment: I was also thinking the same, but just wanted to be sure before creating a plugin for this

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, that you want to extend something in the framework itself, not just add custom field to the API request/response, right? If just add new field then extension attributes is the way to go.

Comment: I just wanted to log the requests sent to the Web API of magento REST or SOAP for audit purposes

Comment: Then plugin should be good.

Comment: Already implemented and it is working as expected

Thanks for you answer!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add something to the response you may want to look into `extension_attributes`. Here is description in magento [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html) and here another question on [stack](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87452/how-do-the-extension-attributes-work-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know maybe this is a dirty way, override this class

```
Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Router::match()
```