# Magento 2.3 : Add free product in a cart after applying coupon

Tags: magento2.3, coupon-codes

How to add product in a  cart with custom price 0 after coupon code success. what is the way to achieve this.
pls help me with the couponcode success event name.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122184/72911)

Yes there is.

The event you're looking for is `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost`

This is generic event that is dispatched before the action class that adds/removes the coupon is called.

As **this is the same event for both add and remove** you can add the following code at the top of your observer method to check if this is a remove action:

```
$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
$remove = $controller->getRequest()->getParam('remove');

if ($remove) {
    // This is a remove action
} else {
    // This is an add action
    $coupon = $controller->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');
}
```

However, when you add a coupon from the checkout flow it won't work as it directly calls the API and there are [no events in Magento 2 web APIs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122184/72911)

The solution is to use a plugin on `Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement` on the `set` method:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement">
        <plugin name="checkout_coupon_apply"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CheckoutCouponApply"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then your plugin class:

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CheckoutCouponApply {

    public function beforeSet(CouponManagement $subject, $cartId, $couponCode)
    {
         // Do what you need to do
    }
}
```