# How to use extension_attributes in Magento2

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

Is there anyone that can give me an example on how to use `extension_attributes` in Magento2?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it was not so clear to me

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87452/how-do-the-extension-attributes-work-in-magento-2

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Suppose we create an order delivery date, when the customer select shipping then the customer can select a delivery date. So you can create a extension attribute for 
**\Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface** in following way

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="delivery_date" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

So now you can access this value when you using **\Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface** as di.

So in that case **Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement** this class use **\Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface** as a params for saveAddressInformation method. So you can access following way:

```
$extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
$deliveryDate = $extAttributes->getDeliveryDate();
```

[For more details](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html)(Magento 2 Official Documentation)

Here is an example:

[extension_attributes](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/blob/master/SR/DeliveryDate/etc/extension_attributes.xml)

[Pick Extension Attributes value](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/blob/master/SR/DeliveryDate/Plugin/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php)

[Update]

You can set extension_attributes by **setExtensionAttributes** method. Following class is an example:
[Click Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/Plugin/AfterProductLoad.php)

Comment: So what is setExtensionAttributes for?

Comment: I updated with real example

Comment: Great, but one thing is missing here: Where exactly are extension attributes stored? Do I have to provide code for saving and retrieving attributes myself or can Magento handle that (like with custom attributes)?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that plugins are mandatory in order for `extension_attributes` to work? For example, do I always have to add a plugin for `afterLoad` for customers if I want to have a custom attribute for customers? Seems like a bit overhead to me ...

Comment: you can also add join directives to the extension attributes if the value comes from another table. Although I did not find a solution yet to save/load them in/from the same table without using a plugin

Comment: Thanks @SohelRana, It's working fine in default Magento setup, but when I install OneStepCheckout module then i can't get value in the post, I mean in quote object so what should i need to change for that....
I get this type value in quote object 

[delivery_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
 
?

Comment: Hi @SohelRana can you please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219230/magento-2-how-to-add-extension-attribute-value-to-response

Comment: I have created extension attribute and i am able to save extension attribute to billing and shipping address but i need to show when use rest/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/billing-address and rest/V1/mine/:cartId/billing-address these APIs

Comment: @MartinWickman yes it is the responsibility of the developer to implement logic for retrieving and persisting of extension attribute data. The concept is, you have some possibly complex data introduced by your Module for Product Entities and this data might come from one or more database tables, or some other data source, it should not matter. Using the Plugin system, target the ProductRepository's methods for loading (e.g., afterGet, afterGetList). Here, you retrieve your data (from wherever) and add it to the Entity's ExtensionAttributes. This seems arduous but is very flexible and powerful.

Comment: Why we use extension attributes ?