# How to add column using extension_attributes.xml in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1.3

How to add column using extension_attributes.xml in magento2 ?

Comment: refer  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113447/how-to-use-extension-attributes-in-magento2