# Magento 2 add custome attribute to soap api in order list

Tags: magento2, soap, soap-api-v2

I have created one custom fee attribute for order i need to add this attribute to soap api can any one tell me

Comment: Create Extension attribute for that API

Comment: @AdityaShah may i know  how to create i have added Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface.php in this file but not getting

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113447/how-to-use-extension-attributes-in-magento2 Ifallowed this answer